# How to read in a list of names separated by commas Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, sorting

So I have an assignment to read in animal's common names and scientific names from a text file, separated by commas. (ie. dog,Canis lupus). Sort them alphabetically by Common name first and print to console, then sort alphabetically by Scientific name and print to console. I'm having issues with a class to read in the file and place them into an array. Sorry if this code is horribly wrong, I'm still learning. Here is the code that's giving me issues:

```
String[] commonname = new String[25];
String[] scienname = new String[25];
    public static String readNames(String[] commonname, scienname) throws IOException { 
         BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                try {
             inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/C:/Desktop/animals.txt"));
          String line = null;
          while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
              Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
              sc.useDelimiter(",");
              String common = sc.next();
              String scient = sc.next();
              String list = new String(common, scient);
          }
                }
         finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

I'm getting 2 errors,

```
"
File: C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Program5.java  [line: 16]
Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
File: C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Program5.java  [line: 16]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
"
```

I already gave the ( in the line it's asking for, and the ; shouldnt be needed as far as I'm aware. 
It's very incomplete, and I'd love help just reading the names into a string that has both the Common and Scientific names, but can be sorted alphabetically by either or if that makes sense. 
Here's the entirety of the code if that sheds any light:

```
/**
 * Auto Generated Java Class.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program5 {
String[] commonname = new String[25];
String[] scienname = new String[25];

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String list = readNames;
  Arrays.sort(list);
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    System.out.println(list[i]);


public static String readNames(String[] commonname, String[] scienname) throws IOException { 
 BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        try {
     inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/C:/users/Nathan/Desktop/animals.txt"));
  String line = null;
  String[] list = new String[25];
  while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
      sc.useDelimiter(",");
      String common = sc.next();
      String scient = sc.next();
      String list = new String(common, scient);
  }
        }
 finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What sort of issues are you having?

Comment: Sorry, just added the error messages below the code

Comment: The term you're looking is "comma-separated-values"

Comment: where is your catch block?

Comment: I was more worried about getting the errors taken care of before writing the catch block @an

Comment: yes but perhaps you can catch the exception in the catch block and that might give you the exact error location etc.

Comment: also your list is being initialized and manipulated at each iteration.

Comment: I'm super new to java, could you explain what that means and why it's a problem? @AnuragJoshi

Comment: sure. So what you are doing in String list = new String(common, scient); is that you are creating a new "list" for each line. So when you reach a new line, the earlier line that you read is vanished because you did not store it anywhere.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: to solve this @NRitH said, you need to create a new ArrayList or so and store each line that you read in this list. This way you wouldn't overwrite pre existing data. Understood?

Answer (score 1):

The line reading and parsing looks fine, but you're not storing the `list` anywhere. Before your `while` loop, declare a container for your pairs. You can use an `Array`, but since they have to be sorted alphabetically, you may as well throw them into a `TreeSet<(String,String)>`, which will sort them for you. To print out the sorted list, call the set's `iterator()` method to loop through its values.

Comment: Added "String[] commonname = new String[25];
String[] scienname = new String[25];", I've never used the TreeSet or iterator in the class before, is there a way to do it using an Array and sort it in the Array?

Comment: Also I'm still getting the same errors telling me I need a "(" where there already is one, and that I need a ";" where I already have one. Any clue what is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your issues is in the constructor

```
readNames(String[] commonname, scienname)
```

You need to define a type for `scienname`.

i.e.

```
readNames(String[] commonname, String[] scienname)
```

The second error, mentioning a missing `;`, is being cause by the compile error mentioned here.

Fix both, and it is my assumption that both errors will go away.

*edit*

Pasted this into my IDE, and found more issues

```
String list = new String( common, scient );
                  /\ the constructor for string takes many things, two String arrays is not one of them.
```

[Available `String` constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String()) here.

And

> This method must return a result of type String

Your method never returns a value, however its defined return type is that of `String`.

After adding the missing `String[]` in the constructor, I am no longer seeing the issue posted in the question.

**edit edit**

I do not have the time to debug you application, and you have some call that I am unsure of your intentions. Here is your code, with some changes, that will compile. You can touch it up from here.

```
public class JTest
{

    static String[] commonname = new String[25];

    static String[] scienname = new String[25];

    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws IOException
    {

        // make a call to the rean names method with parameters
        String list = readNames( commonname, scienname );

        // not sure what you intend to sort, you can not sort a string
        // Arrays.sort(list);

        // for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        // System.out.println(list[i]);
    }

    public static String readNames( String[] commonname, String[] scienname )
        throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

        try
        {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "/C:/users/Nathan/Desktop/animals.txt" ) );
            String line = null;
            String[] list = new String[25];
            while ( ( line = inputStream.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner( line );
                sc.useDelimiter( "," );
                String common = sc.next();
                String scient = sc.next();

                // not sure what your intention is here
                //String list = new String( common, scient );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( inputStream != null )
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }

        // return a String, as specified in method definition
        return new String("with some content");
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the above to `code` "public static String readNames(String[] commonname, String[] scienname) throws IOException { " `code`

Comment: Changed the above to 'public static String readNames(String[] commonname, String[] scienname) throws IOException { ' but I still get the same two errors.

Comment: Sorry I can't edit comments yet and I'm new to how this site formats. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: Oh? Give me a minute, spinning up my IDE to test. `code goes between two \`ticks\` in a comment`.

Comment: See my edit. It appears as if the constructor fix was causing those two issues you posted, but you now have _different_ issues that need to be fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to message you privately? I'm still super confused and the fix made more errors than they fixed :(

Comment: That fix did not make any errors. The compiler was just able to make it farther, and show you what errors you have ;)

Comment: The same errors are still there but now I have an extra constructor error

Comment: Now in the above posted code, you are attempting to define `public static String readNames` before you ever close the definition for `public static void main`.

Comment: Oh god I am so lost... so should I move the readNames to before the main?

Comment: See my final edit. I do not have much time, but I made your program compile - you will need to touch it up a bit from here to preform functionally the way you would like. I have fixed some syntax error, and comment out others.